# Can XPathNavigator.Evaluate(string) return null?

Tags: c#, resharper, nullreferenceexception

Can this overload of [`XPathNavigator.Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8(v=vs.110).aspx) return null ?

```
// Can "result" be null ?

object result = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate(xpathString);
```

If the answer is No, then why Resharper says that `result` maybe null ?

```
string str = result.ToString();    // Resharper: Possible NullReferenceException
```

I found nothing in the documentation about an input that might cause it to return null. I also tried inspecting the [Reference Source for this function](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/XPath/XPathNavigator.cs,0dae423e2499a46b), but it was unfruitful.

I know that [R# uses code annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html), but I still don't trust this warning as I tried different inputs with none of them returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, it does look like it would be highly unlikely to get a `null` from `XPathNavigator.Evaluate`. There are a couple of possible code paths that *might* get you a `null`, but I suspect they're pathological edge cases (if evaluating a function that should be a number function, but isn't, or if the operand to a query is already `null`). I doubt these would happen under normal circumstances.

I don't know why ReSharper has the `[CanBeNull]` annotation on the return value. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because the method is virtual, and therefore there's no way to guarantee that the implementation will always return a value. Or because it calls an abstract method on another class that doesn't have any null-ness guarantees, and there's no check on the return of that value, so again, there's no guarantee that it won't be `null`.

The annotations are based on static control flow analysis, and that can only get you so far. ReSharper will provide the strongest hints that it can. If it knows it's not `null`, it will annotate it so, if it doesn't know, it will flag it `[CanBeNull]`, and err on the side of caution.